# Is there a (literature-)algorithm for splitting up nodes into one node per incoming edge?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, split, graph-theory

Is there a (literature-)algorithm for splitting up all nodes that have an indegree > 1 into one node per incoming edge, so that each split-up node has only one of the incoming edges and all of the original outgoing edges?

Example:
Suppose we have this directed graph: A <-> B <-> C   (directed edges from A to B, B to A, B to C and C to B)

B has an indegree of 2, which means that B should be split up into two nodes, each of which has one of the incoming edges as well as all of the original outgoing edges.

The algorithm should change this graph into something like this:

A -> B_A

B_A -> C

B_A -> A

C -> B_C

B_C -> A

B_C -> C

Also, I'd be glad if you could propose a suitable datastructure to store the resulting graph (please keep in mind that the nodes of the original graph represent grid coordinates and therefore the vertices of the resulting graph should, too).

Comment: I don't see any particular algorithmic difficulty here. Put your graph in an adjacency list; Iterate over nodes; make new nodes and connections for every node x with indeg > 1; remove the node x from the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I created an ultra simple graph description as input. It is a semicolon separated list of "Vertex -> Vertex1, Vertex2, VertexN".

I think, everybody can easily understand:

```
std::string graphDefinition("a->b; b->a,c,d; c->b; d->b");
```

Unfortunately I need 15 lines of code, to split this up and convert it in my graph representation. And that is basically an adjancy list. I use a

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>
```

The first string is the "From"-part and the `std::vector` constains all "To" or "Target"-Vertices.

For building the DirectedGraph I made a separate function.

An additional function converts the DirectedGraph into your specified format. For that it checks, how many times a Vertex appears on the right (target) side. These are Vertices with more than in-arrow. For those, I check, in which edge they are, and then create a new Vertex consisting of the found vertices.

At the end, I iterate through the graph again and add all edges where there was only one Vertex on all right sides of all edges.

I am sorry that this is a bit complex. But please read and digest.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <regex>
#include <map>

// Sime typedefs
using Vertex = std::string;
using TargetVertex = std::vector<Vertex>;
using FromTo = std::pair<Vertex, Vertex>;
using DirectedGraph = std::map<Vertex, TargetVertex>;

// Build a directed graph from a given string in a special format
DirectedGraph buildFromDefinitionString(std::string& s) {
    // Local lamda to trim strings
    auto trim = [](const std::string& s) { return std::regex_replace(s, std::regex("^ +| +$"), "$1"); };
    std::regex re1{ ";" }; std::regex re2{ "->" }; std::regex re3{ "," };

    // Split source line along ";"
    TargetVertex edge(std::sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), re1, -1), {});

    // Split substring along "->"
    std::vector <FromTo> fromTo;
    std::transform(edge.begin(), edge.end(), std::back_inserter(fromTo), [&re2](const std::string& s) {
        TargetVertex ft(std::sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), re2, -1), {});
        return std::make_pair(ft[0], ft[1]);});

    // Split target strings along ","
    DirectedGraph directedGraph;    
    for (const FromTo& ft : fromTo) {
        TargetVertex tv(std::sregex_token_iterator(ft.second.begin(), ft.second.end(), re3, -1), {});
        // Build graph
        for (const Vertex v : tv) {
            directedGraph[trim(ft.first)].push_back(std::move(trim(v)));
        }
    }
    return directedGraph;
}

DirectedGraph convert(const DirectedGraph& dg) {
    DirectedGraph result{};

    for (const auto& ge1 : dg) {
        // How many times is a vertex on the right hand side        
        size_t sum{ 0 };
        // Count all occurences of current evaluate vertex on target side
        for (const auto& ge2 : dg) {
            sum += std::count(ge2.second.begin(), ge2.second.end(), ge1.first);
        }
        // So, now we have the sum of occurrences
        std::cout << "Vertex " << ge1.first << " is " << sum << " times a target\n";
        // For all vertecis with indegree > 1
        while (sum-- > 1) {
            // Go again through the complete directed graph and check, where the current vertex is on the target side
            for ( auto& ge2 : dg) {
                if (auto search = std::find(ge2.second.begin(), ge2.second.end(), ge1.first); search != ge2.second.end()) {
                    // Build new string
                    Vertex newVertex = ge1.first + "_" + ge2.first;
                    result[newVertex] = ge1.second;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // For those where there is only an indegree of 1
    for (const auto& r : result) {
        if (r.first.size() > 1) {
            result[r.first.substr(r.first.rfind('_')+1)].push_back(r.first);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    // A lambda for printing a graph
    auto printGraph = [](DirectedGraph& dg) { for (const auto& ge : dg) 
        for (Vertex v : ge.second)  std::cout << ge.first << " --> " << v << "\n"; };

    // The definition string for our graph
    std::string graphDefinition("a->b; b->a,c,d; c->b; d->b");

    // Build our graph data structure
    DirectedGraph dg1 = buildFromDefinitionString(graphDefinition);
    printGraph(dg1);

    // Convert it as per task definition
    DirectedGraph dg2= convert(dg1);
    printGraph(dg2);

    return 0;
}
```